# Is it possible to express a check constraint?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm doing code-first development with Entity Framework 4.3 and it doesn't seem like it's possible to express a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) via attribute annotations or, well, any other means.  I see that EF 5.0 will be adding support for [checking enumerations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx), but that's not exactly what I'm after here.

To give a simplified example, I'd like to validate that all `Person` objects have a first name of either "Bob" or "Harry" and are either 5, 10 or 30 years old.

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [Check("Bob", "Harry")]  //yes, this attribute is imaginary
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, Check(5, 30, 50)]  //check is still imaginary
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I can run an alter script to add these constraints after the fact and I can roll my own check attribute to perform validations, but is there a way I'm missing to actually express non-enumerated CHECK constraints in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write one yourself (untested):

```
public class CheckAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
{
    object[] ValidValues;

    public CheckAttribute<T>(params T[] validValues)
    {
        ValidValues = validValues;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return ValidValues.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Equals(value)) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did write my own check attribute (that looks eerily similar to yours), but my issue is that this is a domain-only attribute - it's not reflected in the backing table entity with a check constraint there as well in the same way that, say, a string's MaxLength gets reflected in the table structure.

Comment: I'm not all that well versed in EF but I opened `EntityFramework.dll` in ILSpy and it looks like `System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder` is responsible for analyzing the attributes and deciding what to do about them. It looks as though `RequiredAttribute`, `MaxLengthAttribute`, `StringLengthAttribute`, and `DisplayAttribute` are basically hardwired into the database creation process. I'm not sure it is possible to do what you're after with EF as it is today.

Answer (score 6):

I've been wanting to put Check constraints in, and while there are a couple of ways to do it like the answer given here by M.Babcock and using the ExecuteSql in the Initializer to add constraints to the database manually.

But I think the easiest method is to use a `RegularExpression` annotation, so in your example you'd go:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"Bob|Harry")]  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, RegularExpression(@"5|30|50")]  
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This only works if your check constraint can be validated by a regular expression. This works for the //simplified examples// of the OP. In other case, a custom validation, as described by @M.Babcock will be useful.