# EF self-referencing with constraints Many to Many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a class with a **self-referencing relation**. The class is as follows:

```
public class TableActivity
{

    public TableActivity()
    {
    }

    public int TableActivityID {get;set;}
    public string Table {get;set;}      
    public Activity Activity {get;set;}

    public virtual ObservableCollection<TableActivity> RelatedActivities {get;set;}
}
```

in my context class

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableActivity>() 
        .HasMany<TableActivity>(t => t.TableActivityID) 
        .WithMany() 
        .Map(m => 
        { 
             m.ToTable("RelatedActivities"); 
             m.MapLeftKey("TableActivityID"); 
             m.MapRightKey("RelatedTableActivityID"); 
        });

    }
```

I want to add 2 **spesific constraints**:

1. A TableActivity Object can't have itself listed in the RelatedActivities
2. For example if we have 2 TableActivity objects o1 and o2 if o1.relatedActivities.contains(o2) then o2.relatedActivities can't have o1 listed

How to achieve this two constraints ?

***What I have Done*** :

I created a helper class that inherits ObservableCollection and I managed the add methode.

```
public class RelatedTableActivityCollection :ObservableCollection<TableActivity>
{


    private TableActivity m_Owner;
    public RelatedTableActivityCollection(TableActivity owner)
    {
        this.m_Owner = owner;
    }

    public new void Add(TableActivity item)
    {
        if (m_Owner.Equals(item)) {
            return;
        } else {
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem with this solution is that it works fine on the application but nothing is done in the database side. Is there a way to make the database take consideration of this changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the database side you can enforce your restrictions with check constraints. You have not specified which DBMS you are using, but in SQL Server, the first check constraint is simple:

```
alter table RelatedActivities add constraint CK_RelatedActivity check (TableActivityId <> RelatedTableActivityId)
```

The second condition is more complex because you have to inspect other entries in the table. That is possible, but you need a scalar function that does that (with schemabinding). You can call this function from a second check constraint.

Your problem is that with code first you can not easily add check constraint [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232777/check-constraint-entity-framework) to see how to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for your time and ur guidlines.

Answer (score 0):

On the database side I enforced two constraints (to answear the requirements),
the first one is as @Sefe answered, the second one is by using a scalar function as @Sefe suggested

```
alter table RelatedActivities add constraint CK_RelatedActivity check (TableActivityID <> RelatedTableActivitiyID)

alter table RelatedActivities add constraint CK_RelatedActivityRelation check (dbo.CheckRelatedActivities(TableActivityID,RelatedTableActivitiyID)<1)
```

Definition of the Scalar function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckRelatedActivities](@TableActivityId int,@RelatedTableActivityId int)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here 
    DECLARE @Result int 
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

    select @Result = count(1)
where @TableActivityId in (select RelatedTableActivitiyID from RelatedActivities where TableActivityID = @RelatedTableActivityId)


    RETURN @Result

END
```