# EF Core Check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to add a check constraint to a table via EF core.

I have been looking around the only question I found is for Ef 7 with an anwesr over a year ago. So I am just wandering if anything has changed. Which gave the answer as below:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (SomeColumn >= X);");
```

Is there another way to do this? I want to apply a unique constraint as below:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_t_parent_child ON t(parent, child)
WHERE isdeleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your entity is defined as

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public int Child { get; set; }
}
```

Following fluent API code will create index as you desire:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasIndex(p => new {p.Parent, p.Child})
        .HasFilter("isdeleted = 0")
        .HasName("unq_t_parent_child");
```

SQL generated

```
CREATE INDEX [unq_t_parent_child] ON [Entity] ([Parent], [Child]) WHERE isdeleted = 0;
```

`HasIndex` defines index over properties in the table `Entity`

`HasFilter` allows you to set a filter for your index. This value is sql so you need to make sure you are writing correct sql syntax.

`HasName` configures the name of the index.

(If you map `Entity` to table `t` & the properties to their column names, migrations will create exactly same sql as you want.)

Also a check constraint is different from unique index. If you are looking to add check constraint then you need to use `migrationBuilder.Sql` in your migration file.

Answer (score 3):

For newcomers to this in 2021+. EF Core 3+ has support for check constraints.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199728/1179562

Answer (score 2):

Unique constraint **is not check** constraint, anyway, you can create it this way:

```
alter table dbo.t
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_parent_child UNIQUE (parent, child)
```

Comment: I missed one detail here: your index was **filtered** index, but there is no "filtered constraint"