# Entity Framework - how to set column as unique related to another column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using Entity Framework and I have the following model class:

```
public class Test 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }    
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I set the column `IsPrimary` to be unique in accordance with the `SiteId`?

For example I can have multiple records with the `IsPrimary` set to false for the same `SiteId`, but only one set to true.

Comment: Are you looking to enforce this in the database or in the application?

Comment: Assuming the database, you could look into using a check constraint: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13232777/5803406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found the solution! i can have multiple rows for the same siteId when isPrimary is false but only one when the isPrimary is true.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
            .HasIndex(b => new { b.IsPrimary, b.SiteId })
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("IsPrimary = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following codes:

```
[Index("Index_SiteId_IsPrimary", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int SiteId  { get; set; }

[Index("Index_SiteId_IsPrimary", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
```