# Entity constraint "check" with code-first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I made a table to associate a store with Table1 OR Table2 (and other infos)

```
Id
IdStore_FK
IdTable1_FK
IdTable2_FK
SomeOtherFieldsThatDoesntMatterRightNow
```

And I created a check constraint to make sure that it will NEVER have both FK's filled at the same time, and only one of them must be filled (XOR):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE0 ADD CHECK ((IdTable1_FK IS NULL AND IdTable2_FK IS NOT NULL) OR (IdTable1_FK IS NOT NULL AND IdTable2_FK IS NULL))
```

But I ran that `alter table` **manually** after my `add-migration` and `update-database`. I need to develop those restrictions with code-only, to be able to send to my manager.

#### How can I tell entity framework to create that using only my code?
Is there any DataAnnotation to do that?

I tried to add `modelBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE XXX....")` inside the method `Up` of an specific migration. I can only add that line to the migration file **after** the `add-migration`, which creates the file.

A seed query after every startup checking if the constraint exists, and creating it if don't does not seems cool to me. Also it'll run only if I run the code, and not with the migration/update-database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check constraint entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232777/check-constraint-entity-framework)

Comment: @kettch I actually saw that question before, which is what made me try the `modelBuilder.Sql("...")` thing. But back in 2012 there was no .Net Core. Just thought maybe EntityFramework could have implemented that after it's rework for Core. (EF 6.1 implemented a way to create indexes with annotations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it using just code. However, you can leverage the EF migration process to [run arbitrary SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232777/check-constraint-entity-framework). You can also [run sql during the database initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first) in case you need to start with a fresh database.

That being said, [a custom validation attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588606/is-it-possible-to-express-a-check-constraint) might still be a good idea so that you can catch errors earlier.

Sorry for the meta answer, but these are resources that have helped me in the past.

Comment: I actually liked [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425371/8242325) approach you linked, which appears to run only at the database initialization, and not everytime I startup my application, gonna check how to implement that on Core. I don't think a custom validation could work for me, as it apparently works only for **ONE** property (I have IdTable1_FK and IdTable2_FK, and one's validation depends on the other)